# How do I control two subscriptions to display within a single template?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, spacebars

Sorry kind of new to the Meteor framework!

I Subscribed to two Publish functions. Even if both publish functions target the same Collection, they both have different functions, that I would like to display in one template. How do I achieve this. I have done allot of research but there doesn't seem to be sufficient information on how to achieve.

Following are the two publish functions in code that I subscribe to:

.server/main.js:

```
Meteor.publish('MerchantTrending', function (categoryMan){
var currentUser = this.userId;

return buyList.find({ who:"Merchant", ownerId:currentUser, itemCategory: { $in: categoryMan } }, {skip: 0, limit: 3});

});
```

.server/main.js:

```
Meteor.publish('myTopViews', function (){

var currentUser = this.userId;
return buyList.find({ newArrivalsExpiryDate : {'$lte': new Date()}}, {ownerId:currentUser }, {skip: 0, limit: 3});
});
```

Following is the subscription function in code

.client/main.js:

```
Router.route('/MerchantLandingPage', {    
subscriptions: function(){
      var categoryMan = Session.get('category');

    return  Meteor.subscribe('MerchantTrending', categoryMan, 'merchantTopViews')

}
});
```

Now the helper function in code:

```
Template.MerchantLandingPage.helpers({

  'top3Trending' : function () {    
    return buyList.find({}).fetch();
    },

 'myTopViews' : function () {

    return buyList.find({}).fetch();
    }
});
```

And now the template in code:

```
<template name="MerchantLandingPage">

##### *** Top three trending items *** ########

{{#each top3Trending}}

ItemName::  <b>{{itemName}}</b> <br>
Item Category:: <b>{{itemCategory}}</b> <br>                 
Discription:: <b>{{descriptions}}</b> <br>  
Image:: {{this.photo._id}} <br> 
Date Created:: {{createdDate}} <br>  

{{/each}}

<br><br>

 ############ *** My top Views *** #############

{{#each myTopViews}}

ItemName::  <b>{{itemName}}</b> <br>
Item Category:: <b>{{itemCategory}}</b> <br>                 
Discription:: <b>{{descriptions}}</b> <br>  
Image:: {{this.photo._id}} <br> 
Date Created:: {{createdDate}} <br>   

{{/each}}

</template>
```

Both {{#each myTopViews}} and {{#each top3Trending}} successfully display but not correctly. When the variable `categoryMan` in

Meteor.subscribe('MerchantTrending', categoryMan, 'merchantTopViews')

changes value, it affects both both the outcome of both `{{#each myTopViews}}` and `{{#each top3Trending}}`, when its only supposed to affect `{{#each top3Trending}}`.

How can I get the subscriptions to NOT have an affect on both `{{#each myTopViews}}` and `{{#each top3Trending}}`, but only `{{#each myTopViews}}` in my template?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about publishing the collection from server with necessary fields and apply the selectors in client side?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Meteor!

The solution is straight forward once you understand that:

1. Subscription is just a stream of your DB documents from server into your client's MiniMongoDB. So your 2 subscriptions (it is perfectly fine having several subs on the same Collection) just fill in your client's `buyList` local collection.
2. Use of Collections client side is generally independent from how you subscribe the data. So you should simply use a similar selector and possibly options in your `top3Trending` and `myTopViews` helpers as you have done for your publication server side (not the same between the 2 helpers, obviously).

As a side note, you do not even need to `fetch()` the Collection cursor returned by `find()`, Blaze knows how to handle it directly.

Comment: Regarding your first point, In my case, my subscription to  `MerchantTrending` while sending the variable `categoryMan` messes up the returned cursor. Let me explain. `categoryMan` is a dynamic array caring information generated from checked/unchecked boxes in the html form. The returned cursor depends on the checked checkboxs in the html form. I would be desirable for only the `top3Trending` section in the template to respond to the checked/unchecked boxes and not both `top3Trending` and `myTopViews`.  I don't quite understand your second point. Kindy clarify.

Comment: Maybe you should do more tutorials first, you sound to be trying to manage too much complexity at the same time. Forget about Pub/Sub (for now) and just try to display what you need with Client code.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your code, first of all - your second subscription isn't going to work because your query is wrong:

```
Meteor.publish('myTopViews', function (){

    var currentUser = this.userId;
    return buyList.find(
        { ownerId:currentUser, newArrivalsExpiryDate : {'$lte': new Date()}},
        {skip: 0, limit: 3}
    );
});
```

You had `ownerId: currentUser` wrapped in curly braces, it is fixed above.

The way publications/subscriptions work is, if you have two publications sending different data, the template doesn't 'know' the data is coming from two different subscriptions. It will just have access to all of the data being sent by all subscriptions.

For that reason, your two helpers `top3trending` and `myTopViews` are returning exactly the same thing. You can delete one of them!

You should move your subscriptions out of the router and in to the Template itself. [Here's an article that will help you with that!](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/publication-and-subscription-patterns)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what is happening in my Template, specifically how the template fails to notice the how the information is coming from two different subscriptions, and therefore combining the information. Moving the subscription from the router to the template itself didnt make a difference because, remember the Meteor.subscribe('MerchantTrending', categoryMan, 'merchantTopViews') takes in a variable that changes the data returned for both subscriptions.

Comment: @perusopersonale  Just to further clarify, the main culprit here is the `MerchantTrending` subscription as it sends the publication the `categoryMan` variable.  This variable is in form of an array. The array carries information based on the checked checkboxs values. This then affects the cursors response, making it dynamic. I need to figure out how to separate the cursor of each subscription in the Template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [percolate:find-from-publication](https://github.com/versolearning/find-from-publication) that permits to filter the data from publications.

Comment: Thank you. But either there isn't sufficient information on how to use this package or it isn't able to resolve my issue. Just to further clarify, the main culprit here is the `MerchantTrending` subscription as it sends the publication the `categoryMan` variable.  This variable is in form of an array. The array carries information based on the checked checkboxs values. This then affects the cursors response, making it dynamic. I need to figure out how to separate the cursor of each subscription in the Template. Is this possible?