# Meteor publish overwrites another publish

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I have two publish method as below but when I subscribe to one of the publish method in client search page, it is being overwritten with the other one which is meant for index page.

Server

```
Meteor.publish("task.index", function() {
  TaskCollection.find()
}

Meteor.publish("task.index.search", function(state) {
  TaskCollection.find({ state: state })
}
```

Client - search page

```
Meteor.subscribe("task.index.search", state)
// this will always be overwritten with "task.index" published collection
```

Client - index page

```
Meteor.subscribe("task.index")
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

There is a high chance the "override" you see is just the normal Meteor behaviour for Publish/Subscribe mechanism.

Your `"task.index"` publication sends *all* your `TaskCollection` documents to the Client.

Therefore any other publication on that same `TaskCollection` will send documents that the Client already knows.

Then in your Client, filtering some documents from `TaskCollection` is *independent* from your subscription and publication. Just perform your `TaskCollection.find({ state: state })` Client side, and you will get the documents you need.

When you publish only a subset of documents of a Collection, it happens that what you publish is *exactly* already the filtered documents that you want to display on your Client, therefore on your Client you just display all Collection documents you know of. But you have to understand that these are 2 different steps:

1. Subscription to send some documents to the Client. Several Subscriptions may be set, filling the *same* Collection on the Client.
2. Filtering on the Client, based on the documents sent by the (possibly several) Subscription(s).

See also: [Publish subscribe doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138129/publish-subscribe-doesnt-seem-to-work/43141415#43141415)

Answer (score 0):

If your client index and search pages are different templates, you can subscribe to the documents at respective template level.

Client - search page:

```
Template.search.created = function () {
    const template = this;
    template.subscribe('task.index.search', state);
}
Template.search.rendered = function () {
    console.log("Client search : " + TaskCollection.find().fetch().length); 
}
```

Client - index page:

```
Template.index.created = function () {
    const template = this;
    template.subscribe('task.index');
}
Template.index.rendered = function () {
    console.log(""Index : " + TaskCollection.find().fetch().length); 
}
```

But, it is always advisable to filter the documents on the client as well.