# When subscribing to collection with params returns undefined

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I am trying to sub to a collection called `items`, but every time I try to sub with a limit or skip, it returns the whole collection because it thinks the params are undefined.  For example, I am trying to render 1 item from the collection:

```
Meteor.subscribe("items", 1, 0);// 1 item, 0 skip
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  console.log(items.find({}).fetch());
})
```

When I do this, the entire collection gets printed.  In the server, when I print the params of the publication:

```
Meteor.publish("items", (l, s) => {
  console.log(l, s);
  // returns: undefined undefined
  //          1 0   
  return items.find({}, {limit: l, skip: s});
})
```

And on the client side, I get all the documents rendered instead of just the one.  Is there something I'm missing here or doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you still have the `autopublish` package installed, which automatically publishes and subscribes to your entire collection.

So it looks like you reach the step where you should remove that package (`meteor remove autopublish`).

Furthermore, on your Client, make sure you also filter the query on your collection, otherwise you may get polluted by parallel subscriptions that fill data into the same collection, as done with `autopublish` for example.

See also:

- [Meteor publish overwrites another publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754845/meteor-publish-overwrites-another-publish/46755108#46755108)
- [Overlapping Meteor publications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006793/overlapping-meteor-publications/44007620#44007620)

Comment: Then you have another subscription that receives documents in your same collection.